# How to validate form using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to validate form using react hooks ?

I used class components and it worked great, but now decided to use functional components with hooks and don't know the best way to validate form.
My code:

```
const PhoneConfirmation = ({ onSmsCodeSubmit }) => {

    const [smsCode, setSmsCode] = useState('');

    const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (smsCode.length !== 4) return;
        onSmsCodeSubmit(smsCode);
    }

    const onValueChange = (e) => {
        const smsCode = e.target.value;
        if (smsCode.length > 4) return;
        setSmsCode(smsCode);
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={smsCode} onChange={onValueChange} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
};
```

It works but I don't think it's good idea to use handler function inside functional component, because it will be defined every time when the component is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you can slightly improve it because you [don't need a controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Moreover, you can [memorize the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) so it won't make unnecessary render on `onSmsCodeSubmit` change due to its parent render.

```
const FORM_DATA = {
  SMS: 'SMS'
}

const PhoneConfirmation = ({ onSmsCodeSubmit, ...props }) => {
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(e.target);
    const currSmsCode = data.get(FORM_DATA.SMS);
    onSmsCodeSubmit(currSmsCode);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit} {...props}>
      <input type="text" name={FORM_DATA.SMS} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

// Shallow comparison by default
export default React.memo(PhoneConfirmation)
```

[image: Edit Q-57648264-FormSubmit]